# How to load Image or svg src through react map from states?

Tags: reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/load-svg-from-import-via-states-6ycf4q

I am trying to load svg icons in map from state objects but the state is not loading in img src. please help

```
   {Tabs.map((obj, i) => (
                  <Card className="">
                    <Card.Body>
                      <i className={obj.icon}></i>
                      <img src={obj.iconsvg} />
                      <Card.Title>{obj.tabtitle}</Card.Title>
                      <Card.Link
                        key={i}
                        onClick={() => setActive(obj.tabname)}
                        className="tab"
                      >
                        Click to see more <img src={linkarrow} />
                      </Card.Link>
                    </Card.Body>
                  </Card>
                ))}
```

Comment: What is `Tabs.iconsvg`?  The use of `Tabs.map` implies that `Tabs` is an array, and arrays have no property called `iconsvg`.  Did you mean to use `obj.iconsvg` instead?

Comment: I was trying to call iconsvg. 
obj.iconsvg loading imported svg names like this only <img src="cardicon1">

Comment: At a glance, and without knowing more (linking to an external example can be useful, but all relevant information should be in the question), this just looks like a typo.  Everywhere else in the code is referencing properties on `obj`, except the only one which "isn't working" is referencing a property on the array itself.  Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you import your icons as

```
import cardicon1 from "./cardicon1.svg";
```

you must reference this at your `iconsvg` property

```
  {
    tabname: "tab2",
    tabtitle: "Chart Color Pale111ttes",
    icon: "fas fa-palette",
    iconsvg: cardicon1
  },
```

Check [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/load-svg-from-import-via-states-forked-kwqwv0?file=/src/Datacomponent.js)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `iconSvg` as a string value. Instead of that, you need to use the image address that you imported.

Check the updated sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/load-svg-from-import-via-states-forked-pffjp9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark